# Movie about an alien girl with human parents, all three trying to run away

Tags: story-identification

I remember a movie on TV from a few years ago. It was about a kid (I think a girl?) who was an alien, and her human parents were trying to run away with her. Some guys kidnapped her and took her to a rundown shack. At some point in the film, she was in a van with her parents, and a man who was also an alien, and I think he was related to the kid.

Does anybody know what this movie was called?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might mean the Taken miniseries ([imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0289830/)). While the story in the series spans 3 generations in the last episode there is a similar situation to what you are describing [youtube link to specific scene with the van](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksK1CUi8hcM#t=133)

spoilers:

> the girls grandparents were all abducted by aliens in the first episodes (they are the first generations) while the middle episodes focus on the girl's parents who are also abducted. also if memory serves me right one of the grandparents is the alien in the van.

All in all it's a fun series to watch.